# Identify the original printer

Tags: c#, printers

I am enumerating printers connected in the PC. I done it using C# `System.Printing` namespace.
It works well. But mostly it shows software printers like *Microsoft XPS Document writer,Microsoft Fax* etc. I would like to know is it possible to remove these ssoftware printers from enumeration. The code I have done is show below :

```
PrintQueue printQueue = null;

LocalPrintServer localPrintServer = new LocalPrintServer();

// Retrieving collection of local printer on user machine
PrintQueueCollection localPrinterCollection =
    localPrintServer.GetPrintQueues(new[] { EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Local,
                                            EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Connections });

System.Collections.IEnumerator localPrinterEnumerator =
    localPrinterCollection.GetEnumerator();

while (localPrinterEnumerator.MoveNext())
{
    // Get PrintQueue from first available printer
    printQueue = (PrintQueue)localPrinterEnumerator.Current;

    if (!printQueue.IsOffline)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(printQueue.FullName.ToString());
        string s = "Printer found " + printQueue.FullName.ToString();
        listBox1.Items.Add(s);
    }
    else
    {
        // No printer exist, return null PrintTicket 
        // return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way I found is to compare the name of desired printer with the one we are getting.

Answer (score 12):

The key to distinguishing a real printer from a virtual printer is the port the printer is using.  Real printers use hardware ports such as LPT1: or USB ports.  Virtual printers use software-driven ports.

The complication will be network printers.  It won't be easy determining if a network printer is using a hardware port.

I know this isn't a great answer but you've posed a very difficult question.  I hope it gets your started in the right direction.

Comment: I've given this a lot of thought over the last few days, and I think I know the Windows printing subsystem as well as anyone outside of Microsoft, and... well, I'm afraid I don't think there is a way to reliably distinguish between a hardware and a virtual printer in all cases.  I could give you a "usually right" solution, but I don't think an "always right" solution is possible.  Sorry.  :-(

Answer (score 3):

Few observations:

1. In the `Properties` window the `Device Settings` Page is available ONLY for the Real Printers and NOT for the Virtual Printers. And most of these values are available in `printQueue.UserPrintTicket` property
2. `printQueue.QueuePort.Name` contains an `IP` address appended with or without the port name. ex: "20.120.12.22_1" or "20.120.12.22" for Real Printers

[image]

Comment: The print driver and port monitor control both these things and can do as they please.  I can show you examples that don't match your findings.

Comment: @Zigma: Sorry, I haven't observed it, does it contain an `IP` address also? Any drivers you could point me to..

Comment: no just the portname. ports will be network routers or something like that.

Comment: @Zigma: Ok.. My objective was just to `hint` on which could be the possible cases to filter thing out..

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Print Spooler API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162861%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to manage printers and printjobs. Specially the [EnumPrinters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162692%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function might be useful for you. You can grab the c# wrapper from [Pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/winspool/enumprinters.html)